# Indexes broken after database copy/move

Tags: mysql, indexing

I recently consolidated several databases on a single much more powerful server. They have several dozen tables each with the larger ones having 2-6 million rows each. I noticed that some queries that were running in around 15ms were now taking a full 10 seconds to finish.

I ran mysqlcheck -c on the databases which reported everything was okay with each table. I then tried to optimize the tables anyways. That did not work. What did work was manually deleting every single index and recreating it.

I'm a novice when it comes to DBA. Why isn't optimize fixing any broken indexes? Is there hopefully a better way to do this than having to manually delete a little over 1000 indexes and recreate them?

Thanks for your help and replies.

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB?  Did you tune key_buffer_size or innodb_buffer_pool_size to account for the bigger machine?  Please give an example of a query that took a lot longer (there may be clues in it); and include the SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql the indexes are always balanced trees. The engine is updating them and keeping them optimized. You should not need to delete and recreate them. Probably the performance will not change if you recreate them all.

Did you analyze the queries that are now slower? Try to optimize them and the indexes that are related to them. Use `explain` to show the query execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lorenz. Deleting and recreating the indexes does improve the performance. Query goes down from about 10s to 15ms which is huge. Below are the explains for an identical query, on identical databases which are on two different servers.

Comment: Faster result: http://antoniopita.com/d/ed.htm, Slower result: http://antoniopita.com/d/ed2.htm

Comment: Are the servers identical?

Comment: No the one with the faster result has a slower dual core processor with 2GB of ram being shared with the other applications. The slower result comes from the new server with 16GB of RAM and two quad core processors with only MySQL running . I'm including the my.ini I generated with Percona: http://antoniopita.com/d/my.ini

Comment: The two results of `explain` are visibly not the same. The slower includes an additional `file sort`, which explains that it is slower. Unfortunately I can't tell why.

Comment: Here's what I found on percona's blog http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/